# An injectivity criterion for $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ as $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, injective-module

Let $R=\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ where $m>1$. Show that $R$ is injective as an $R$-module iff for any abelian group $A$ such that $mA=0$ and for any subgroup generated by an element $a\in A$ of order $m$ is a direct summand in $A$.

It seems to me the problem must somehow be reduced to a case of $m=p^k$ where $p$ is prime but I don't know how. I don't really understand how to chose complement to $\langle a\rangle$, too.

Could you please help me?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, pardon, of course $m=n$.

Comment: That's a funny exercise, because actually $R$ *is* an injective $R$-module.

Comment: Actually (For commutative Noetherian $R$ and nonzero ideals $I$) $R/I$ is self-injective over itself if and only if 1) $R$ is a dedekind domain or 2) $R$ is Artinian PIR, or 3) $R$ is local with maximal ideal has composition length 2 and squares to zero.  This is a (to me famous) result by Lawrence Levy: https://msp.org/pjm/1966/18-1/pjm-v18-n1-p14-s.pdf

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ falls into the "Dedekind domain" bucket, as does any PID

Comment: Do you know that a module is injective iff whenever it is a submodule it is a direct summand?  The statement you are trying to prove follows pretty much immediately from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first just uncode what the given statement has to do with $R$-modules for $R=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.  An "abelian group $A$ such that $mA=0$" is just the same thing as an $R$-module.  A "subgroup generated by an element $a\in A$ of order $m$" is then just a submodule of $A$ that is isomorphic to $R$.  So the given condition just says "for all $A$ and $B$, if $A$ is an $R$-module and $B$ is a submodule of $A$ isomorphic to $R$, then $B$ is a direct summand of $A$".

This condition "for all $A$ and $B$, if $A$ is an $R$-module and $B$ is a submodule of $A$ isomorphic to $I$, then $B$ is a direct summand of $A$" is one of the several commonly used equivalent definitions of what it means for an $R$-module $I$ to be injective.  So, if this is your definition, you're done.  If you use some other definition, you just have to prove this definition is equivalent to your definition.  (Depending on what exactly your definition is, one direction of this equivalence may be a bit nontrivial.  You may find it helpful to use fact that every module is a submodule of an injective module, and so the condition above then would imply your module is a direct summand of an injective module.)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ *is* an injective $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$-module. More generally, [Baer's criterion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Baer%27s+criterion) states that an $R$-module $A$ is injective if and only if for every ideal $I \subseteq R$ any morphism $I \to A$ can be extended to a morphism $R \to A$. For $R=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ the category of $R$-modules is isomorphic to the category of abelian groups with $mA=0$, and ideals have the form $n \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(m/n)\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n \mid m$. A morphism $I \to A$ corresponds to some element $a \in A$ with $(m/n) a = 0$, and it extends to $R \to A$ iff $a \in nA$. So we see that $A$ is injective iff
$$A \xrightarrow{~~n~~} A \xrightarrow{m/n} A $$
is exact for all $n \mid m$. This easily checked for $A=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, so $R$ is injective as an $R$-mdodule.

From this the implication $\Leftarrow$ follows, and $\Rightarrow$ follows by applying injectivity to the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \cong \langle a \rangle \hookrightarrow A$ and the identity of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

Maybe the proof of the equivalence was intended to be different, but it works.

Comment: The equivalence being asked about in the question is almost immediate from the definition of injectivity.  I suspect it is intended as the first step of a proof that $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ actually is injective over itself (without going through Baer's criterion).

Comment: For me, it's not "immediate" ... since cyclic submodules have orders $n$ dividing $m$, not nec. $m$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the relevance of cyclic submodules is.

Comment: The condition in the question is just a paraphrase of the statement "whenever $R$ is a submodule of another $R$-module, it is a direct summand".  If that's your definition of what it means for a module to be injective, then you're done.  If you have a different definition, you have to do a little work to show your definition is equivalent to that one.

Comment: Well, that "little(?) work" is exactly the question here. I am very interested to see your answer then. :) For example, I do not see how that immediately follows from the characterization injective <=> it is a direct summand when it's a submodule.